# How to show physics bodies during runtime in Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a composite physics body that is behaving strangely during runtime. Is there a way to display physics bodies during runtime in Spritekit?

Comment: Set `showsPhysics` on the view to `true`

Comment: Btw you should put that into an answer so I can give you credit and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Set `showsPhysics` on the view to `true`.